# unable to add values to array

Tags: javascript

A few weeks ago I posted my code, that was supposed to add values to an array and then draw rectangles on a canvas. The idea is to start drawing a rectangle where other finishes. Youe write width and height values, click on abutton, round this values and the draw it. But unluckily it doenst work.The problem is that the first value is added to the array, but not the next.. Im working JavaScript. Here is my code, any help will be welcome.

```
var arrayLargo = [];
var arrayAncho = [];
var ancho = 0;
var largo = 0;

function corta() {
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var medida2 = document.getElementById('medida2').value;
var medida1 = document.getElementById('medida1').value;
  var corte1 = Math.round(medida1);
  var corte2 = Math.round(medida2);


  arrayLargo.push(corte2);
  arrayAncho.push(corte1);
  //ancho, largo


//metodo para el ancho

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayAncho.length ; i++) {
        ancho += arrayAncho[i];
    }
    if (arrayAncho.length == 1) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#58FA58";
        ctx.fillRect(0, largo, corte1, corte2);
    }else
    if (medida1 > 122 - ancho) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "#58FA58";
            ctx.fillRect(ancho, largo, corte1, corte2);//ancho, largo
        }
    else {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#58FA58";
        ctx.fillRect(ancho, largo, corte1, corte2);//ancho, largo
    }


    medida1 = 0;
    medida2 = 0;

    /*  
   //metodo para el largo
   if (arrayLargo.length >= 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLargo.length ; i++) {
        largo += arrayLargo[i];
        if (medida1 > 244- largo) {
            ctx.fillRect(0, largo, corte1, corte2);//ancho, largo
        }
       }
   }*/
```

}

function corta is called when you click on a button

Comment: Er, sorry but "Here's my code, it doesn't work" is not the kind of question this site encourages. Feel free to edit it and explain how exactly it fails to work. Also, do some basic debugging yourself and isolate the part of the code what "doesn't work".

Comment: ok álvaro, lo unico que "falla" es la adicion de valores al array, el rsto lo hace perfectamente. Y gracias pòr el aviso! :)

Comment: Your problem is not your English. Your problem is your (lack of) problem description. :)

Comment: the problem is that the first value is added to the array, but not the next.

Comment: @user2051485: So you’re saying that after calling the `corta` function twice, both the `arrayLargo` and the `arrayAncho` only contain **one** element?

Comment: Thats what i believe, due to it only draw one rectangle

Comment: That's what you *believe*? Better make certain of that!  Add a line `console.log("arrayLargo", arrayLargo);` at the end of the `corta` function, and see what shows up in the error console! Or, alternatively, set a breakpoint in the corte function, and see when it is triggered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few tips to help you get useful answers (or better yet, to let you solve the problem yourself)

1. What are you expecting the code to do, and what does it do instead?
2. Are you getting an error message? (Don't forget to check the error console). If so, what is it, and on which line does it occur?
3. Have you tried reproducing the problem in a simpler setting? (Making a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) can be a great help.)  If so, what was the result?

Comment: On the simple way to draw omly a rect works fine, but when I try to addd some new values it doesnt do it. My personal believe is that may Im not referencing both arrays in the right way